# How to remove: rpmdb failed release provides

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I am trying to execute command yum search livy and getting following error:

> CRITICAL:yum.main:
>
> Error: rpmdb failed release provides. Try: rpm --rebuilddb

I tried below steps to resolve the error:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*

db_verify /var/lib/rpm/Packages

rpm --rebuilddb
```

All the above commands are running successfully, but when I run yum command after this, I am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late for you but it might help, ran into the same issue today.

Other that a reinstall of the system I didn't find anything useful, here's what I did (I have TSM as backup solution):

I did a restore of the files in /var/lib/rpm from 2 days ago:

```
mkdir rpmstuff

dsmc restore -pitd=05/03/2020 "/var/lib/rpm/*" "/root/rpmstuff/"
```

Be sure to kill of any processes if they are running:

```
ps -ef | grep 'rpm\|yum'

kill -9 pid
```

Remove the files that are currently in the directory, hidden ones also:

```
cd /var/lib/rpm

rm -rf *

\rm .dbenv.lock .rpm.lock
```

Copy the recovered files:

```
cp -av /root/rpmstuff/rpm/* .
```

Then:

```
\rm -rf __db.00*

rpm --rebuilddb

yum clean all

yum repolist
```

Worked for me, hope it helps.

Have a good one!

Comment: Kinda obvious to use a backup but I didn't think of it. I solved this on a group of workstations using a copy from a different _healthy_ machine in the group; otherwise confirmed identical. Since it had started out broken, I didn't feel the need to run any checks, and all `yum` commands worked fine, including `yum update`. _If there was any minor variance_ in installed packages, it's safer to follow this path and be able to patch, than not patching.